# Why can't I use Capistrano's info method in my task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I'd like to output something in an overridden Capistrano task using `info`, like capistrano-rails does (e.g. [here](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/b5f41b6482a0f481077f351d058307b9b29c9fac/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake#L13)).

But with this task:

```
namespace :deploy do

  if ENV['DB_MIGRATE'] == 'skip'
    Rake::Task['deploy:migrate'].clear_actions

    desc "Override Capistrano's default behavior, do not migrate on deploy"
    task :migrate do
      info '[deploy:migrate] Skipping migrations due to DB_MIGRATE=skip'
    end
  end

end
```

I get this error:

```
$ DB_MIGRATE=skip bundle exec cap staging deploy:migrate
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `info' for main:Object

Tasks: TOP => deploy:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**What do I have to do to use `info` in my own task?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano exposes the `info` method inside `on` blocks

http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html

> Capistrano exposes the methods debug(), info(), warn(), error() and
>   fatal() inside of on() blocks which can be used to log using the
>   existing logging infrastructure and streaming IO formatters:

Comment: Does the same apply to `run_locally` blocks?